Number of ways of coloring an $m \times n$ grid such that every $2 \times 2$ square is distinct?
I recently thought of a somewhat interesting problem, which, while I've given some thought, I have no idea how to approach. The problem is stated as follows:

Given an $m \times n$ grid ($m, n > 2$) and $k > 1$ colors, how many ways are there to color the grid such that every $2 \times 2$ square is unique (up to rotation)?

I am aware about the fact that a lot of coloring problems similar to this one are open problems in mathematics (see coloring a grid such that no two adjacent squares are identically colored). However, I was wondering if anyone had any ideas going about solving something like this problem in particular?

What does it mean to say that every 2x2 square is unique?  Can you specify what that means, mathematically?

Sure. But given the context I think it's pretty clear, no? A $2 \times 2$ colored square $A$ is equivalent to $B$ if $B$ exists in the orbit of $A$ under $C_4$.

Please revise the question rather than putting clarifications in the comments.We are trying to build an archive of knowledge for the ages.  Thank you!
